# ASP.NET table gridlines property not working?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get an asp.net table to show gridlines after an sql query is ran and data is put into the table. I have now tried to set a default title row to see if the gridlines would even appear and they have not.

Here is my table markup:

```
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" Height="330px" Width="950px">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="5px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#993399" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top">
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Customer ID</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Business Name</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">City</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">State</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Phone</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Email</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Registered</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Approved</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Last Contacted</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Logger</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell runat="server">Responded</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
```

So, how can I get grid lines to show on my asp.net table?

Comment: I forgot to add that I have tried using just vertical and just horizontal gridlines. In my example above, I use "both".

Comment: Why not use a `GridView`?

Comment: I've never used a GridView... Looks exactly like what I want. Thanks Garrison!

Comment: You'll love all of the built-in functionality the GridView provides.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

BorderColor property should make them visible. Since the background is white, try setting the the BorderColor to Black.

Comment: Nothing changed when i changed borderColor to black. I also tried this with some borderStyles and different BackColors.

Comment: Hmm, it worked for me in VS 2010 before posting this. Looks like you found the GridView though! Good luck!

Comment: Not sure what was going on... Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Border=1 in your table tag.

Comment: Hey there, you're probably right, but this problem is 8 years old and I probably won't go back to verify this :p